# how to add my location to google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-maps

How to add source address in android for opening google maps with source and destination address?

I have tried the following:

```
String map ="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=My+Location&daddr="+address;

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(map));
i.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(i);
```

I am getting error in map application as "no result for my location"

My requirement is that I want to open google maps application with user current location and destination address which i am passing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q=", "ahmedabad");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i itried this one but its not working.i want from field in maps set with "your location" as we get in uber and ola apps

Comment: Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+address);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);                                                                                 address is String variable which holds my destination address